# convert object keys and values in single Array JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const dataObj =
{"Tom-29":[ 
    { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
]}
```

I want something like below and result sorted by number

```
[
   Name:"Tom",
   Age:29,
    [{"number": 12, "string": "hi"},
    {"number": 40, "string": "bye"}]
];
```

How would i do this ? I tried below approach .

```
 const arr =Object.entries(dataObj).map(itm=>({...itm,Name:itm[0]}));
```

Please help me to resolve

Answer (score 2):

You can use the object key and append it to each of it's children as a name.

```js
    const dataObj =
    {"Tom-29":[ 
        { "number": 12, "string": "hi"},
        { "number": 40, "string": "bye"}
    ]}

    const results = Object
      .keys(dataObj)
      .map(k => { 
        dataObj[k].forEach(i => { 
          i.name = k.split('-')[0]; 
          i.age = k.split('-')[1]; 
        }); 
        return dataObj[k] 
      })
      .flat();

    console.log(results);
```

Comment: Name and age need to separated

Comment: I've updated that for you.

Comment: @Pellay one-liners are mostly unreadable. Could you separate it out a bit?

Comment: @Andy of course. It kind of grew a little. :)

Comment: @Pellay Sorry i have printed wrong format of result.I have edited my results.please help me\

Comment: It's impossible to have an object in the format you want output. It's not valid as and array or an object. you can't have `[ key:value ]` in an array and you can't have `{ [{ key:value }] }` in an object. I could produce a string that looks like this, but no-one can create an object/array in that format. It's not valid Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the `dataObj` entries with `Array.flatMap()`, extract the `name` and `age` from the `key`, and then map the values, and add the properties to the original object using array spread:

```js
const dataObj = {"Tom-29":[{"number":12,"string":"hi"},{"number":40,"string":"bye"}]}

const result = Object.entries(dataObj)
  .flatMap(([key, values]) => {
    const [name, age] = key.split('-')
    
    return values.map(v => ({
      name,
      age: +age,
      ...v
    }))
  })
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry i have printed wrong format of result.I have edited my results.please help m